# Is there a way to constify of a variable after declaring it?

Tags: c++, c, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some ninja trick to make a variable constant after its declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669315/is-there-some-ninja-trick-to-make-a-variable-constant-after-its-declaration)

Sometimes in C or C++ we have a variable that might be const, but we have to take some lines of code to initialize it.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that, from some point in a function, some already constructed variable has to be considered as const, until its scope ends?

Something like:

```
int c = 0;
// the value of c is initialized here
switch(someVar) {
   case foo: c = 3; break;
   case bar: c = 4; break;
   default : c = 42; // what else?
}
// now c is constant
ASSUME_CONST_FROM_NOW(c) // some #pragma maybe?
```

*I know that I could initialize the variable in a dedicated function*. This is not really what I am asking for.

Another example:

```
int c = 0; int d = 0;
{ /*some block of code that initializes both c and d jointly*/ }
ASSUME_CONST_FROM_NOW(c, d)
```

There is no function that can return two values at a time without creating structures or classes.

But such a trick could be useful in order to make old, crappy code more easily understandable with not much refactoring.

Comment: @MSalters: thanks, had not seen that one.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? More specifically, why is it so important, that you'd be ready to use non-standard and not-portable #pragma's to achieve this? Anyway, basically (in C) you can't "constify" a non-const variable. Once a variable is non-const, you can (should you want) safely cast away any const-qualifiers to access that variable.

Comment: It's not an exact duplication, because there is no hint on allowing C++0x solutions in this question. Trying to come up with a complicated C++03 solution for the other question would be a bad/unnecessarily-complex answer. For this question as currently stated, it would be a necessarily-complex answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Put the initialization in a function.

```
int getInitCValue(int const& someVar)
{
    // the value of c is initialized here
    switch(someVar)
    {
        case foo: return 3;
        case bar: return 4;
        default : return 42; // what else?
    }
}

int const c = getInitCValue(someVar);
```

#### Edit: To answer the modified question.

You want to initialize two values:

```
std::pair<int,int> const value = initalizePairOfValues(someValue);
int const& c = value.first;
int const& d = value.second;
```

#### Edit 2: Go with Péter Török deleted solution (Peter if you un-delete I will remove this).

```
struct ConstValues
{
    ConstValues()
    {
         switch(....)
         // Initialize C/D
    }
    int const& getC() const {return c;}
    int const& getD() const {return d;}
    private:
       int c;
       int d;
};
```

Comment: ...you mean initialize via a function?

Comment: This is exactly what I told in the end of my question. I know this is the way I should do it. But sometimes this advice would lead to too much work. Sometimes, also, be could initialize two variables in the same time.

Comment: @Benoit: You are wright you can't return two values without making a class. But you can use a class that already exists. std::pair<> is very good for two values and boost::touple<> is very good for a set of values.

Comment: @Benoit: use `boost::tie` with  @Martin York's suggestion for this.

Comment: I think you mean `std::pair`, I corrected your post if you don't mind.

Comment: @Benoit: If the variables are that closely related, then maybe they should be in a class. Then they can be initialized in the class's constructor.

Answer (score 9):

In C++0x, you can do something like this:

```
int const c = []() -> int { 
    int r; 
    switch(42) { 
    case 3: 
        r = 1; break; 
    case 4: 
        r = 2; break; 
    default: 
        r = 23; 
    }; 
    return r; 
}();
```

Comment: I don't know why but it looks like Javascript...

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to provide some `{}` around the code that is to see the variable `const`, yes, at least something similar. Put something like the following in a macro:

```
#define CONSTIFY(T, NAME)                  \
for (bool p00 = true; p00; p00=false)      \
for (T p000 = NAME; p00; p00=false)        \
for (T const NAME = p000; p00; p00=false)
```

this should work in C99 as well as in C++. Technically, this doesn't make your original variable `const` but creates a new variable with the same contents for the depending scope.

And beware that in some cases (`break` or `continue`) this might change the control flow. But as long as you wrap this around something which is basically a whole function body, this should work.

Comment: smart, but this is asking for a world of pain later... :D

Comment: @Nim: One should probably not leave this in the code, I agree. But for the purpose of checking some legacy code quickly to see if there is somewhere an attempt to change the variable, this might still help.

Comment: Besides this, this could lead to data loss if copy constructors (like with `auto_ptr`s which, I agree, should not be used) are tricky.

Comment: @Benoit, I am too much thinking in C nowadays. With `int` as in the question this shouldn't change much. For C++, yes indeed that already supposes that a copy constructor is accessible. Why this would lead to dataloss, I don't get.

Comment: auto_ptr destructor calls delete[]. Therefore it should never be copied if the intent is to share the pointer, only when the owner of the pointer should be transferred.