# Recapture const-ness on variables in a parallel section

Tags: c++, variables, constants, openmp

I have the following code:

```
const W = (f.IsUnit() ? U : modq.Multiply(m_pre_2_3q, U));

const Integer t = modp.Multiply(modp.Exponentiate(V, 3), eh);
const X = (f.IsUnit() ? t : modp.Multiply(m_pre_2_9p, t));
```

When converted to OpenMP, the const-ness is lost:

```
Integer W, X;
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        W = (f.IsUnit() ? U : modq.Multiply(m_pre_2_3q, U));
    }

    #pragma omp section
    {
        const Integer t = modp.Multiply(modp.Exponentiate(V, 3), eh);
        X = (f.IsUnit() ? t : modp.Multiply(m_pre_2_9p, t));
    }
}
```

How do I recapture the const-ness on `W` and `X` when they appear in parallel sections?

Comment: Does deferred construction break openMP?  Do you have `std::experimental::optional` or `boost::optional`?

Comment: @Yakk - I think OpenMP is probably OK. But the library uses C++03 (and not C++11 or Boost), so its not available.

Comment: `optional` can be written yourself, deferred construction (esp if on a platform with weak alignment requirements) even easier.  Try placement new in to a buffer, and const reference access?  I'd be more concerned about create-and-assign than `const`

Comment: Just a quick explanatory note (since OP has enough rep to see deleted answers) - I had posted an answer involving using const_cast, but I deleted it rapidly because I realised it got into undefined behaviour. Ignore it!

Comment: @David - forgive my ignorance... How did it get into undefined behavior?

Comment: @jww - this answer explains it reasonably well I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/357607/4657412.

Comment: @Yakk - you might be able to answer this question: [Is there some ninja trick to make a variable constant after its declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3669315)

Comment: @David - Thanks. I actually got into trouble like that some time ago. But it was a POD, and not a complex type. I had a test harness that had `const byte[]` of 1 character, and cast away const-ness. GCC put it in a register so that the modification to the array did not work and caused a crash. The modification were trivial: I tried flipping a bit with `arr[0] ^= 0x01;` (I was testing authenticated encryption routines).